# split sequences

Tags: c#

I have a list `List<int> myList = new List<int>(){1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 12, 18, 19, 31};`

What I'm trying to do is to split the sequences that occur.

For Example
In the above list I have 1, 2, 3 number in sequence
what I need is something that find the number in sequence and return something like this:

```
number 1 sequence 2.
number 5 sequence 1.
number 8 sequence 0.
number 12 sequence 0.
number 18 sequence 1.
and so on...
```

What I have tried so far

```
for (int i = 1; i < myList.Count; i++)
        {
            if (myList[i - 1] + 1 == myList[i])
            {
                count++;
            }
            else
            {
                if (count != 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine( myList[i - count - 1].ToString() + " " +count.ToString());
                    count = 0;
                }
            }
            
        }
```

Comment: _"What I have tried so far"_ -> And what's wrong with that?

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(myList[i - count - 1].ToString() + " " +count.ToString());` to print the digit at the start of the sequence.

Comment: And if you want to print the single number sequences, remove `if (count != 0)`

Comment: It seems you want to split the list into sequences `{1, 2, 3 | 5, 6 | 8 | 12 |  18, 19 |  31}`.

Comment: This looks like homework or a interview question,  getting other people to do the work for you is not useful,  also having the question on stackoverflow is unlikely to benfit people searching on Google.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Thanks, I try to figure out How to print just the first number and the sequence that occur.

Comment: @IanRingrose this is not HomeWork sir! It just a part of my app

Comment: @JAlex, exactly right, I made simple the example above but actually I'm working with bytes of 16bit Big and Little. and need to split the sequence of them

Comment: @Backgroup - I suggest you [edit] the question with exactly that (split sequences) because the wording now is ambiguous imho.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of tracking the count, I'd track where the sequence starts instead:

```
int seqStartIndex = 0;

for (int i = 1; i < myList.Count; ++i)
{
    if (myList[i - 1] + 1 != myList[i])
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"number {myList[seqStartIndex]} sequence {i - seqStartIndex - 1}.");
        seqStartIndex = i;
    }
}
```